# Would the "general nature of a trap" be its category?

Tags: dnd-5e, spells, traps

The Find Traps spell says:

> You don’t learn the location of each trap, but you do learn the general nature of the danger posed by a trap you sense.

Would that mean you know the category or type of trap, but not the exact effect if you trigger it?

For example, say I have a pit covered with a rug. The pit has spikes (slashing damage) with poison on them (poison damage) and the ceiling will also crumbled by some magical means (bludgeoning damage from those falling rocks.)

What the heck do I tell the cleric when he casts the Find Traps spell?!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

“General nature of the danger” is just plain English, not a secret code. It means: describe the nature of the danger, in general terms (i.e., not specific terms).

The general nature of the danger posed by the kind of trap you describe would actually be two traps: “there's a pit trap and a collapsing ceiling trap.” So I guess that, yeah, the general category of the trap would be the right response.

If the description seems vague, *general*, and lacking in specifics (“but shouldn't I mention the spikes and the poison and the fact they trigger at the same time and…?!”) then you're on the right track for following the spell's instructions correctly. Anything about it that starts with “the exact…” is almost certainly too specific to be revealed by the spell.